# How to get screen_view distribution in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

In Google Analytics, we can easily view the average screen_view count or screen_view time. I wonder if it is possible to record the distribution of the screen_view count and screen_view time? (e.g. whether it is normal distribution, what is the skewness, what is the top 20%, etc.)

I'm using flutter and simply recording through FirebaseAnalyticsObserver.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Data Studio and import data from analytics and make your custom explorer accordingly. For example.

[image]